# EMF and internal resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

Why  emf doesn't change when external resistance is infinite but changes when finite though internal resistance persist in both cases??

Comment: EMF of what? In what conditions? Produced by what (chemical reaction, magnetic induction,...)?

Answer (score 1):

EMF falls due to current through the internal resistance. If the external resistance is infinite then although internal resistance is still there, there is no current flowing through it and no voltage drop.

Comment: I don't believe this answer to be correct.  The *terminal voltage* falls below the emf when the source is loaded due to the internal resistance but the emf (ideally) remains constant.  For example, from "Fundamentals of Physics, 6th edition":  *The magnitude of the emf for the battery (or other source) is the value of this 'open circuit' voltage. When the battery is charging or discharging, the emf itself cannot be measured directly using the external voltage because some voltage is lost inside the source.*

Answer (score 0):

To a fair approximation most chemical cells behave (unless becoming 'flat') as if they had a *constant* emf, $\mathscr{E}$, even when there are different external resistances so different currents. What *does* change according to the external resistance is the potential difference (pd), $V_\text{term}$, across the cell terminals, that is across the external resistance itself.

The emf is the energy, per coulomb passing, provided by the chemical reactions in the cell. This energy per coulomb (or 'voltage') is shared by the internal resistance, $r$, in the cell and by the external resistance, $R$, through both of which the current, $I$, has to pass. [$r$ and $R$ are in series.] So $$\mathscr{E}= Ir + IR.$$ But $\ \ IR=V_\text{term}$, so $$V_\text{term}=\mathscr{E}-Ir.$$This explains why $V_\text{term}$ is usually less than $\mathscr{E}$; it is because of the voltage drop, $Ir$, in the internal resistance. [$r$ is usually *roughly* constant.] However, if the external resistance approaches infinity, the current approaches zero (because $I=\frac{V_\text{term}}{R}$) so the pd, $Ir$, across the internal resistance approaches zero, so $V_\text{term}=\mathscr{E}$, even though $r$ remains constant.

[If $r$ is very small, $Ir$ will be small, even for an appreciable current. In this case, $V_\text{term}$ won't drop much below $\mathscr{E}$ even when we connect a finite resistance across the cell terminals. It is therefore an advantage for a cell to have a *low* internal resistance: we don't *want* $V_\text{term}$ to drop at all! The voltage drop is a nuisance. We'd really like a cell with an emf of (say) 1.6 V to supply a $V_\text{term}$ of 1.6 V *whatever* we connect across the cell terminals.]

I've always thought that this is quite an intricate argument. I don't think it can be simplified significantly*. You need to think about it step-by step as each individual step is easy. A circuit diagram will probably help. Show the cell as a source of emf (the usual short stroke, long stroke symbol) in series with an internal resistance. Complete the circuit with the external resistance, $R$. Enclose the cell symbol and $r$ by a dotted box to show that both the source of emf and the internal resistance are inside the actual cell.

*Here's an example of a simple-looking but invalid argument. "When we connect a lower resistance, *R*, across the cell terminals, $V_\text{term}$ will naturally become lower (and vice versa) because $V_\text{term}=IR$, and if we decrease the rhs, the lhs must also decrease." Have you seen why this is at best an incomplete argument?